# Positioning text under an image using echo

Tags: php, html, css, image, echo

I am using php to loop through and display all images from a directory. This works, however I want to add the image name underneath each of the images. I am struggling to get the text to center underneath it, as it seems to just place it next to it and appears to be in its own column separate to the image.

How do I go about fixing this? From research I've done the general solution seems to be placing them in a div together, I haven't done much php before but am I able to just stick the two echo statements inside of a div tag?

```
            <div id="contentClothing">  
                <?php
                    function hoodie() {
                        $dir    = 'images/clothing/hoodies/small/';
                        $files = scandir($dir);
                        $images = array();
                        foreach($files as $file) {
                          if(fnmatch('*.png',$file)) {
                            $images[] = $file;
                          }
                          if(fnmatch('*.jpg',$file)) {
                            $images[] = $file;
                          }
                        }

                        foreach($images as $image) {
                          echo '<img src="images/clothing/hoodies/small/'.$image.'"width=15% height=20% hspace=2% vspace=2% data-big="images/clothing/hoodies/large/'.$image.'" />';
                          echo '<span>'.$image.'</span>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Here is the css

```
#contentClothing {
    padding-bottom: 5%;   /* Height of the footer element */
    margin-left: 15%;
}

span {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is how it looks http://puu.sh/m8Zh0/6b0da6ec03.png

Comment: try creating a container elements to encapsulate the image and the span

Comment: As mentioned above, each image and associated text should be wrapped in their own individual div. Then the centering is much easier.

Comment: Tried this (how the answer does it below), it centers the text under the image but is now displaying 1 image per line

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<span>`, use `<p>` tag. Wrap the whole image and text inside `<div>` tag and apply your styles to it.

```
// your code

foreach($images as $image){
    echo '<div style="text-align:center; float:left; clear:right;">';
        echo '<img src="images/clothing/hoodies/small/'.$image.'"width=15% height=20% hspace=2% vspace=2% data-big="images/clothing/hoodies/large/'.$image.'" />';
        echo '<p>'.$image.'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}   

// your code
```

Comment: This works but forces each image on to its own line.
like http://puu.sh/m90jd/d76600b26e.jpg
Any idea on how to keep them on the same line?

Comment: @JustOneTime didn't you use `float:left` as I suggested in the answer?

Comment: I did, I copy pasted it exactly :(

Comment: No change. I checked to make sure that there was no css affecting images or p tags or anything and there isnt. Not sure why its not working :/